# Words "PREV" and "NEXT" display instead of navigation arrows in Swiper + React

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

The arrows don't display. Instead "PREV" and "NEXT" text show in their place.

I've confirmed that the swiper.css is loading. The PREV and NEXT texts are functioning correctly. Clicking them changes the images and also mobile swipe gesture functions as expected.

EDIT: codepen is here: https://codepen.io/davrosfl/pen/OJJPegm
It's strange, it works fine in codepen, but not on my local machine. Same code.

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import './Project2.css';
import 'swiper/css/swiper.css';

class Project2 extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            effect: 'fade',
            fadeEffect: {
                crossFade: true
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="swiper-container" ref={div => this.carouselRef = div}>
                <div className="swiper-wrapper">

                    <div className="swiper-slide">
                        <img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/01.jpg`} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="swiper-slide">
                        <img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/02.jpg`} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div className="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Project2;
```

CSS

```
.swiper-container {
    height: calc( (var(--vh, 1vh) * 100) - 10.75vh );
    width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

I want the navigation arrows to display instead of "PREV" and "NEXT"

Comment: Where is the text "PREV" and "NEXT" coming from? It's unclear looking at the above code.

Comment: can you share a codepen? I don't see any issues

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea I edited with codepen link. It works fine in codepen, but the same code in my env produces the PREV NEXT text.

Comment: css seems to be the issue, can you save swiper.min.css locally and reference that file instead?

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea I did copy the css from https://unpkg.com/swiper@5.0.4/css/swiper.css into a local css file. My class definitions are in the same file and they are being applied. I just did it again to confirm and still showing NEXT and PREV.

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea I found the problem. Appears to be a bug? It's now reproduced in the codepen link. If text-transform: uppercase; is placed in the style of the body tag, it reproduces the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Placing text-transform: uppercase; in the style of the body tag will produce this bug. For ex:

```
body {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```